# Ask Ubuntu and file attachments

Tags: support, asking-questions

I need to attach a log file to a question I'm going to ask on Ask Ubuntu. Is this allowed by the site rules and if yes, how to do it?

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely,

If you have a long log-file, use something like [the Ubuntu Pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and link it up in your question.

This makes the question far easier to read, and neat and tidy questions always have a better chance of getting answered quickly.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Ubuntu Pastebin doesn't support uploads. My file is > 400kb and I don't want to copy/paste the content manually inside a textarea! I'll look for an alternative.

Comment: @Guandalino - a log file that large isn't going to help anyone only copy the information that pertains to your issue.

Comment: Agreed. That's **far** too long. The only point of posting a log file is if you expect somebody to read it. Nobody is going to trawl through something *that* big.

Comment: how is this a good idea? the service explicitly states that it has no guarantees on long-term hosting of content. Stack Exchange is supposed to be about long-term value.